# how to access github using a user name that is local to the current git folder?

Tags: git, github

how to access github using a user name that is local to the current git folder?

I am getting "permission denied to user steve" error on "git push -u origin main" command.

But "steve" is my --global user name.  In this repo, I want to use a 2nd user name and email.
To set the user name in this folder, I ran:

```
git config user.name "localsteve"
```

but I still get the "permission denied to user steve" error.

When I run git config --list, there are two user.name entries:

```
$ git config --list
user.name=steve
user.email=steve@xxx.com
user.name=localsteve
user.email=localsteve@xxx.com
remote.origin.url=https://github.com/xxx/steve.git
```

I ran "git config --unset user.name "steve".  But this has no effect. ( because that is the --global user name? )

How can I pull from a github repo using a user name and email that does not match the --global user.name?

---

update: I can push to the repo by specifying the user name of the repo in the push command:

```
git push https://'localsteve'@github.com/xxx/steve.git
```

But I am prompted to enter the PAT on each push.  How to specify the local user name in the .git folder?

Comment: `user.name` has *no effect at all* on how you access GitHub. It is used *only* when making a new commit locally. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40710850/1256452).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Git FAQ notes](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#user-name) that `user.name` is the name in commits and has no effect on authentication, and that it is customarily a personal name (e.g., “Pat Doe”) rather than a username.

If you need to use multiple usernames on your system, the [Git FAQ also explains how to do that](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#multiple-accounts-http).  Typically, you will want to put the username in the URL, and you will want to configure a credential manager to save your credentials.  If all of your remote URLs contain a username, Git will distinguish the tokens or other credentials and will choose the right one automatically.

If you're being prompted for credentials after entering them, then you probably haven't set up a credential manager correctly.  The [Git FAQ also outlines how to do that](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#http-credentials).  The customary credential manager depends on the operating system.